# Custom "mouseenter" function doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, mouseenter

[Here's the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/C94GH/)

I'm trying to make `mouseenter` work on Chrome, Firefox, etc. using the following function:

```
var addMouseenter = (function () {
    var contains = function (parent, elem) {
            return parent.contains ? parent.contains(elem) :
                !!(parent.compareDocumentPosition(elem) & 16);
        },
        wrap = function (elem, method) {
            return function (e) {
                if (elem === e.target && !contains(elem, e.relatedTarget)) {
                    method.call(elem, e);
                }
            };
        };

    return function (elem, listener) {
        var listener2 = wrap(elem, listener);
        elem.addEventListener('mouseover', listener2, false);
    };
}());
```

Everything worked fine until I ran into this specific situation:

- Element A has one of these custom `mouseenter` listeners
- Element A contains Element B
- Element B is right up against the edge of Element A
- You enter Element A at that same edge

My expectation was that the `mouseover` event would be triggered on Element B and bubble up to Element A. However, that does not appear to be the case. I tested with Chrome 13 and Firefox 3.6 and got the same result. Did I mess something up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason my custom function wasn't firing is because it didn't work.

[I updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C94GH/2/) showing that all is as it should be.

My mistake was only checking to see if `e.target` was the same as the element I had attached the listener to. What I needed to be checking was if they were the same **or** if `e.target` was a *child* of the element.

When you mouse over the two squares really quickly, it only registers the `mouseover` event on the inner one, and because my listener was attached to the outer one, the `elem === e.target` test was failing.

So I changed the `if` code in the `wrap` function to this:

```
if ((elem === e.target || contains(elem, e.target)) &&
    !contains(elem, e.relatedTarget)) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        method.call(elem, e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't oppose using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#first').mouseover(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') != 'second') {
            alert('hello');
        }
    });
});
```

Tried that in your JSFiddle and it works:
when you enter the green square it doesn't fire; when you enter red square from outside it fires; when you enter red square from green square it fires. That's what you wanted right?

[new JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZKHs/)

Or keeping your javascript approach:

```
// Misc set-up stuff
var greet = function () { alert('Hi, my name is "' + this.id + '."'); },
    first = document.getElementById('first'),
    second = document.getElementById('second');

// The Actual Function
var addMouseenter = (function () {
    var contains = function (parent, elem) {
            return parent.contains ? parent.contains(elem) :
                !!(parent.compareDocumentPosition(elem) & 16);
        },
        wrap = function (elem, method) {
            return function (e) {
                //if (elem === e.target && !contains(elem, e.relatedTarget)) {
                if (elem === e.target && (e.target != second)) {
                    method.call(elem, e);
                }
            };
        };

    return function (elem, listener) {
        var listener2 = wrap(elem, listener);
        elem.addEventListener('mouseover', listener2, false);
    };
}());

// GOGOGO
addMouseenter(first, greet);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AUc88/

Comment: @sdleihssirhc the problem is somewhere here: if (elem === e.target && !contains(elem, e.relatedTarget)) change that to if (elem === e.target && (e.target != second)) and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/AUc88/

Comment: I just noticed that if you do enough fast mouseovers over the green square at some point it triggers the alert too. Not sure if anything can be done about this, but that's probably an extreme case...